# DOM - get background element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Consider dragging one element `A` over another element `B`. Now, A is over B. From event I can get target element `A` but is there a way to get underlying element `B` from this event or element. I tried `event.target.closest('.containerElement')` but could not fetch   element B. Element B has "containerElement" class set. `event.target` fetches `Event A`.

I wish to know when element A is completely into the element B. I get element A which is dragged but need to know element behind it.

[image]

Comment: Is B nested of A

Comment: B is just dragged over A. Would not be nested.

Comment: These are siblings in DOM. Element A appears first and then element B.

Comment: This depends very much on what you mean by "A is over B". Do you want to know as soon as A overlaps B even by a tiny amount or do you want to know only when the boundaries of A are totally within the boundaries of B also are both A and B rectangles or are they clipped at all? And please supply a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth - Added screenshot, need to know object 2, when object 1 is dragged into the object 2. When the boundaries overlaps 60%. It is easier with mouse with interact.js but need to detect this with keyboard event.

Comment: 60% of what? Area of B or area of A or both sides of B overlapped by 60% of their dimensions or is that for A? Or are A and B of the same size?

Comment: "*keyboard event*" - how are you "dragging" with the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) which will return a list of the elements which would be hit by a point at x,y, in z-index order:

```js
ondrop = (evt) => evt.preventDefault();
ondragover = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // clean what we may have done last time
  document.querySelectorAll(".dragged-over").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("dragged-over"));
  // get the x & y position of the cursor
  const { x, y } = evt;
  // get all the elements at this position
  const allBelows = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);
  // get only the first one that matches .b
  const firstElBelow = allBelows.find(el => el.matches?.(".b"));
  firstElBelow?.classList.add("dragged-over");
}
```

```css
.a,.b {
  border: 1px solid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.b {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.b.dragged-over {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="a">drag me</div>

<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
```

Now, the `dragover` event actually fires on B (the one that's below), not on A (the `dragstart` event does fire on `A`). So you could also do:

```js
ondrop = (evt) => evt.preventDefault();
ondragover = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // clean what we may have done last time
  document.querySelectorAll(".dragged-over").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("dragged-over"));
  // get all the elements on which this event fired
  const allBelows = evt.composedPath();
  // get only the first one that matches .b
  const firstElBelow = allBelows.find(el => el.matches?.(".b"));
  firstElBelow?.classList.add("dragged-over");
}
```

```css
.a,.b {
  border: 1px solid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.b {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.b.dragged-over {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="a">drag me</div>

<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
<div draggable class="b">drag over me</div>
```